# Ordering by desc distorts when using grouping sets in Oracle

Tags: oracle

I have a following query

```
select to_char(WK_END_DT) AS MTD,CASE WHEN EMP_NAME IS NULL
                THEN 
                'TOTAL'
                ELSE 
                EMP_NAME END AS EMPLOYEE, sum(Trans) AS Trans,sum(Units) AS Units,sum(Sales) AS Sales,sum(UPT) AS UPT,sum(ADS) AS ADS,sum(FICCount) AS FICCount,sum(FICDollars) AS FICDollars,sum(FICPercent) AS FICPercent  from 
                (
                SELECT a16.WK_END_DT,
                         a15.EMP_NAME,
                         COUNT (DISTINCT a11.TXN_NUM) Trans,
                         (  (  NVL (SUM (a11.F_CLRC_SLS_QTY), 0)
                             + NVL (SUM (a11.F_PRMTN_SLS_QTY), 0))
                          + NVL (SUM (a11.F_RGLR_SLS_QTY), 0))
                            Units,
                         (  (  NVL (SUM (a11.F_CLRC_SLS_AMT), 0)
                             + NVL (SUM (a11.F_PRMTN_SLS_AMT), 0))
                          + NVL (SUM (a11.F_RGLR_SLS_AMT), 0)+ NVL (SUM (a11.F_FBC_AMT),0))
                            Sales,
                           round((  (  NVL (SUM (a11.F_CLRC_SLS_QTY), 0)
                               + NVL (SUM (a11.F_PRMTN_SLS_QTY), 0))
                            + NVL (SUM (a11.F_RGLR_SLS_QTY), 0))
                         / COUNT (DISTINCT a11.TXN_NUM),2)
                            UPT,
                         round((  (  (  NVL (SUM (a11.F_CLRC_SLS_AMT), 0)
                                + NVL (SUM (a11.F_PRMTN_SLS_AMT), 0))
                             + NVL (SUM (a11.F_RGLR_SLS_AMT), 0))
                          / COUNT (DISTINCT a11.TXN_NUM)),2)
                            ADS,
                         SUM (a11.F_FBC_QTY) FICCount,
                         SUM (a11.F_FBC_AMT) FICDollars,
                         (round((SUM (a11.F_FBC_QTY) / COUNT (DISTINCT a11.TXN_NUM)),3))*100 FICPercent
                    FROM rdw30_adm_dm.WSL_SLS_TRAN_SKU_LH_DM@PRDRDW.wetseal.com a11,
                         rdw30_adm_dm.TIME_DAY_DM@PRDRDW.wetseal.com a12,
                         rdw30_adm_dm.ORG_LOC_DM@PRDRDW.wetseal.com a14,
                         rdw30_adm_dm.WSL_SALES_ASSOC_DM@PRDRDW.wetseal.com a15,
                         rdw30_adm_dm.TIME_WK_DM@PRDRDW.wetseal.com a16
                   WHERE     a11.DAY_IDNT = a12.DAY_IDNT
                         AND (    ( (a12.WK_IDNT) IN
                                      (SELECT r11.WK_IDNT
                                         FROM rdw30_adm_dm.TIME_DAY_DM@PRDRDW.wetseal.com r11
                                       WHERE r11.DAY_DT BETWEEN (SELECT min(DAY_DT)  FROM rdw30_adm_dm.time_day_dm@PRDRDW.wetseal.com
          WHERE wk_idnt in 
          (SELECT  WK_IDNT
           FROM rdw30_adm_dm.time_day_dm@PRDRDW.wetseal.com
          WHERE day_dt = (TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 7)))
                                                             AND (SELECT max(DAY_DT)
           FROM rdw30_adm_dm.time_day_dm@PRDRDW.wetseal.com
          WHERE wk_idnt in 
          (SELECT  WK_IDNT
           FROM rdw30_adm_dm.time_day_dm@PRDRDW.wetseal.com
          WHERE day_dt = (TRUNC (SYSDATE) - 7)))))
                              AND a14.LOC_IDNT IN (149))
                         AND a12.WK_IDNT = a16.WK_IDNT
                         AND a11.LOC_KEY = a14.LOC_KEY
                         AND a11.SALES_ASSOC = a15.SALES_ASSOC
                GROUP BY a12.WK_IDNT,
                         a14.LOC_IDNT,
                         a11.SALES_ASSOC,
                         a16.WK_END_DT,
                         a15.EMP_NAME  order by Sales DESC)
               group by grouping sets((WK_END_DT,EMP_NAME),(WK_END_DT))
```

I am trying to order it by sales column descending values and in the following format.

```
    "WK_END_DT" "EMP_NAME"  "TRANS" "UNITS" "SALES" "UPT"   "ADS"   "FICCOUNT"  "FICDOLLARS"    "FICPERCENT"
23-JUL-16   "Lalugba, Nea H"    199 605 5888.38 3.04    29.19   4   80  2
23-JUL-16   "Perez, Vanessa"    143 386 3748.35 2.7 25.23   7   140 4.9
23-JUL-16   "Gamarra, Nadim K"  97  269 2659.59 2.77    26.59   4   80  4.1
23-JUL-16   "Nunez, Katherine"  69  222 2314.01 3.22    31.8    6   120 8.7
23-JUL-16   "Hunter-Bullock, Natasha N" 82  218 2170.88 2.66    25.99   2   40  2.4
23-JUL-16   "Baez, Nadia L" 66  168 1713.98 2.55    25.06   3   60  4.5
23-JUL-16   "Christ, Danielle"  68  168 1618.19 2.47    23.21   2   40  2.9
23-JUL-16   "Taveras, Jarissa"  25  68  877.12  2.72    34.28   1   20  4
23-JUL-16   "Montanez, Naomi"   35  82  873.79  2.34    24.39   1   20  2.9
23-JUL-16   "Melendez, Justin"  20  60  647.82  3   32.39   0   0   0
23-JUL-16   "Leja, Agnieszka L" 7   29  332.93  4.14    44.7    1   20  14.3
23-JUL-16   Total                       22845.04
```

But whenever I try to order it according to the above scenario i.e order it by sales desc, the total amount gets on the top of the result set which I do not want. Is there any way to order it in the format I have shown in this question. Which is the total amount should remain at the bottom and the rest of the of the amounts in sales column get ordered by the descending values of the sales column.

Comment: SO: In the two Answers offered so far, we find at least two discrepancies between what you claim your query is and what you claim your output is. In the query you have the alias EMPLOYEE but in the output you still show EMP_NAME. In the query you have 'TOTAL' but in the output 'Total'. How did that happen? Definite de-merit!

Answer (score 1):

```
order by case when emp_name = 'Total' then 1 else 0 end, sales
```

Even though the flag 0 or 1 is not created for the SELECT, it is computed for ordering; ordering by this flag first will guarantee the total is at the end. Everything else is ordered by sales.

NOTE: I don't believe you ran the query you posted and you got the output you posted. In the query you have 'TOTAL' and in the output you have 'Total'. In the ORDER BY clause, match case exactly.

Also, at the top you can replace the CASE expression with `nvl(emp_name, 'Total')`.

Answer (score 1):

1. move your order after `group by grouping sets((WK_END_DT,EMP_NAME),(WK_END_DT))`
2. you order may look like this `order by decode(EMP_NAME,null,1,0), sales`

Comment: With the query as written by the OP, by the time processing gets to ORDER BY, emp_name is no longer NULL for the total row, did you notice that? He changed that to 'TOTAL' in the SELECT clause.

Comment: @mathguy, `CASE WHEN EMP_NAME IS NULL THEN  'TOTAL'  ELSE  EMP_NAME END AS EMPLOYEE` - i don't see where emp_name no longer null.. it's null, but `EMPLOYEE` is not

Comment: Ha - you caught another lie in the OP's post. The query says "as employee" (which you are right, I missed) but the purported output still shows the column as "emp_name". In any case, if the OP had indeed used an alias, you CAN'T order by emp_name anymore. You can only order by columns in the SELECT clause (identified by their alias), and expressions depending on them. But good catch re: alias in SELECT.